# Matlab meshgrid surface understanding problem

Tags: matlab

I have difficluties at understanding the Matlab documentation for the meshgrid, contour or surf functions. I simply do not understand how the matrix Z must be created to display values for x and y vectors.

Basically, I have loop that calculates x(n), y(n) and a value z(n) with n is the index. Now how do I map this into the meshgrid function to create a contour plot from this data?

```
for i = 1:n
   x(n) = i;
   y(n) = i;
   z(n) = rand();
end
```

Now:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = ???;
contour(X,Y,Z)
```

Comment: [griddata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) should prove useful

Comment: You need a value of `z` for every pair of `[x,y]`. In your example, you only define values of `z` for `1:n`, but you need `n^2` values of `z`. Ask yourself, what is the value of `z` in your code for `(1,1)`? and for `(5,5)`? and for `(5,1)`? you simply have not defined such thing. The logic gap escapes ebcause you are using `mesgrid` without really noticing `meshgrid` is inventing many values of `X` and `Y`, but can't do it for `z`. For educational purposes, try to write your own meshgrid that fills up `X` and `Y` and think what could you do with `z`? (answer: not much)

Comment: Your `Z` quantity should be a function of both `x` and `y` ( `z=f(x,y)` ) for it to represent a surface in a 3D space (from which you could draw iso-contours). If `x`, `y` *and* `z` are only vectors (not matrices), then what you have a 3D _curve_, A line which meandres through your 3D space but it doesn't define a surface.